# how can i fix this error in the pubspec.yaml file pertaining to the path dependency?

Tags: dart

Invalid version constraint: Could not parse version "packages/calculator". Unknown text at "packages/calculator".

```yaml
dependencies:
  calculator: 
  path: 'packages/calculator'
  lints: ^1.0.1
```

Comment: The `path: ...` line should be further indented to be under `calculator`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use path not string as value of `path` in pubspec

```
calculator: 
    path: packages/calculator
```

But in this case if you have package in project root you need assign like `../calendar` by two dots you can go back in folders

[Read this doc](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies)

Dont forget pubspec has indent sensitivity

```
calculator: 
    path: 'packages/calculator'
```

Comment: the calculator and the path are under dependencies, I indented the path under the calculator and I run into an error again

Comment: Did you run `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`?

Comment: If it helps, vote to help others too